# Casting issue in LINQ (C# .NET 4)

Tags: c#, linq

I have come across a very confusing problem that I hope someone can help me with.  In my application I have the following data structures:

```
public struct EntityDetails
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeDetails> Attributes { get; set; }
    public bool EntityExists { get; set; }
}

public struct AttributeDetails
{
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool AttributeExists { get; set; }
}
```

I instantiate the object with the following:

```
public static List<EntityDetails> entityList { get; set; }
```

So, what I need to do is to be able to return a filtered list of attributes based on an entity name and an attribute name.  To do this I wrote the following piece of LINQ:

```
public static List<AttributeDetails> GetFilteredAttributeList(string pEntityName, string pAttributeFilter)
{



    return (List<AttributeDetails>)entityList.Where(e => e.EntityName == pEntityName)
                                             .Select(e => e.Attributes
                                                           .Where (a => a.AttributeName
                                                           .Contains (pAttributeFilter)));


 }
```

Initially, when I did this I didn't have the cast at the start, but it brought up a compile time error, so I added the cast to allow it to compile.  However, when it gets to this method I get the following message:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[MPYA.BU.CRMClientUpdateTool.CRMAccess.CRMAccessLayer+EntityDetails,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MPYA.BU.CRMClientUpdateTool.CRMAccess.CRMAccessLayer+AttributeDetails]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MPYA.BU.CRMClientUpdateTool.CRMAccess.CRMAccessLayer+AttributeDetails]'."}

Now, from the research I've done it would be appear that one is of type IEnumerable and the other is list, which I understand, but I can't for the life of me work out how to cast it so it is acceptable!  I've also tried ToList(), casting it through the extension methods and various other things.  I've also confirmed the data structure contains the correct data.

Any help would be appreciated.

## UPDATE

Apologies, but for some reason I can't reply to answers for 8 hrs *sigh*.  I have followed the advice of everyone to use ToList and now I get the following error:

Thanks for the answers so far.  In my mind ToList() was the only logical way to go, but when I do that I get the following compile-time error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MPYA.BU.CRMClientUpdateTool.CRMAccess.CRMAccessLayer.AttributeDetails>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MPYA.BU.CRMClientUpdateTool.CRMAccess.CRMAccessLayer.AttributeDetails>'
```

The actual error message when I hover over it is "System.ArgumentNullException".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply **end your LINQ query with a call to [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)** to convert the results to a `List<T>`.

One thing to keep in mind is that calling `.ToList()` on a LINQ query "realizes" it, meaning that execution is no longer [deferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx);the results are now stored in memory in your `List<T>`.

In addition, I believe you want to **use the [`.SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) clause, instead of `.Select()`**.  `e.Attributes` is a  `List<AttributeDetails>`.  If you use `Select()`, it will create an `IEnumarable<list<AttributeDetails>>`, with each element being the attributes from one of your entities.  **`SelectMany` will combine the returned lists** and return an `IEnumerable<AttributeDetails>`, which appears to be what you want.

Ultimately, you want to use the following:

```
return entityList.Where(e => e.EntityName == pEntityName)
                 .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes
                             .Where (a => a.AttributeName
                                     .Contains(pAttributeFilter)))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You are a genuis!  Thanks very much.  I would vote you up, but apparently I need a 15 reputation to do that!  Thanks a million though.

Comment: Please update your question with the error you posted in your response to @Habib.  That's the only reason I realized you needed `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
 return entityList.Where(e => e.EntityName == pEntityName)
                                             .Select(e => e.Attributes
                                                           .Where (a => a.AttributeName
                                                           .Contains (pAttributeFilter))).ToList()
```

LINQ returns IEnumerable which is not a list, so you cannot cast this object to list. When you call `ToList()` the linq query will be executed and converted to list

Answer (score 1):

You need `SelectMany` to pull out the attributes into a single list.  You also need `ToList()` to convert the result to a List(). The cast will be unnecessary.

Try

```
return entityList.Where(e => e.EntityName == pEntityName)
                 .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes
                                   .Where (a => a.AttributeName
                                                 .Contains (pAttributeFilter)))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `Attributes` are in fact instances of `AttributeDetails`, then you can call `.ToList()` at the end of your query. However, another appropriate way could be for you to change the signature of the method to return an `IEnumerable<AttributeDetails>`, depending on what functionality the caller is expecting.

In fact, the caller can still transform the query results at their leisure if they need to do so, where you can reliably return a further readable and queryable collection. So...

```
public static IEnumerable<AttributeDetails> GetFilteredAttributeList(
  string pEntityName, string pAttributeFilter) {
  return entityList
    .Where(e => e.EntityName == pEntityName)
    .Select(e => e.Attributes
      .Where (a => a.AttributeName.Contains (pAttributeFilter)
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<AttributeDetails> GetFilteredAttributeList(string pEntityName, string pAttributeFilter)
    {
        var entityList = new List<EntityDetails>(); //added just to makte it compile

        var filtered =
            from entity in entityList
            where entity.EntityName == pEntityName
            from attribute in entity.Attributes
            where attribute.AttributeName.Contains(pAttributeFilter)
            select attribute;
        return filtered.ToList();
    }
```